# Swap (remove/add) between sets

Tags: c++, vector, set

My main question is how I can easily swap objects from one vector to another in C++. So adding an object to one vector and removing it from another.

To be more precise: I'm trying to iterate over a grid of cells in the following manner:

1. Add all cells to an unknownset (and one start cell to the knownset)
2. Add the neighbors of the known cell to the candidateset (and remove from the unknownset)
3. Pick the cell in the candidateset with the lowest value and add it to the knownset (and remove it from the candidateset)
4. Pick this lowest cell and return to step 2
5. If the unknownset is empty; quit.

Sloppy pseudocode:

```
vector<Cell> knownset = vector<Cell>();
vector<Cell> unknownset = vector<Cell>();
vector<Cell> candidateset = vector<Cell>();
Cell currentCell = some_cell;
// Iterate until all cells are known
while (unknownset.size() > 0){
    for each (direction in directions){
        c = currentCell+direction;
        // Add cell to candidate set
        candidateset.push_back(c);
        // Remove cell from unknown set
        unknownset.remove(c);
        // Search the cell with the lowest value
        for each( candidate in candidateset ){
            if ( candidate.value < lowestValue ){
                lowestValue = candidate.value;
                lowestCell = candidate;
            }
        }
        // Remove the cell with the lowest value
        knownset.push_back(lowestCell);
        candidateset.remove(lowestCell);
        currentCell = lowestCell;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to easily swap cells in this way? (the grid is quite large, so any tips for the performance are also welcome)

Comment: Did you try `std::swap` included in `<algorithm>` ?

Comment: @Caduchon: And what two objects, exactly, would you swap?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is it.  `std::vector` stores all its content contiguously, so your "swap" of necessity requires copying data around.

You might be eligible for a move optimization, except that you are keeping `currentCell`.  Still, you could move from the location you are about to remove, to a local, and from there to the new location.  It is unclear whether your `Cell` object has a move operation that is cheaper than a copy, so this may not matter to you.

If you want efficient element removal, you should use a datastructure that is optimized for element removal.  If you also need to remember insertion order, then `std::list` might be good.  If ordering is not needed, then `std::unordered_set`.

From your algorithm description, I suspect `std::unordered_set` is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap contents of two vectors v1 and v2, you can use

```
v1.swap(v2)
```

from algorithm library.